# SaltStack: How to implement custom Jinja Filter?

Tags: python, saltstack

I want to extend the jinja filters which are avaiable in SaltStack

I want to create a simple filter called `rpm_to_debian_name`

```
{ package-name | rpm_to_debian_name }
```

I only found docs about the salt specific filters: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/carbon/topics/jinja/index.html#filters

How to extend these filters?

BTW: implementing this filter is **not** part of this question. It is a simple python which is easy to implement. The question is how to make it available, where to put the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja is one of several renderers that Salt supports. The renderers code starts here:  https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/renderers/jinja.py

but it looks like you would add your filter here:

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/a875b9074207108233e96f9e35e630b75ce21cd8/salt/utils/templates.py#L347

I'm not sure if there's a place outside of Salt's codebase to plug that in.
I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the main part of my question is still open. How to plug something into this from a place outside of Salt's codebase? :-)